# read txt file into dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following type of document, where each person might have a couple of names and an associated description of features:

**New person**

```
name: ana
name: anna
name: ann
feature: A 65-year old woman that has no known health issues but has a medical history of Schizophrenia.
```

**New person**

```
name: tom
name: thomas
name: thimoty
name: tommy
feature: A 32-year old male that is known to be deaf.
```

**New person**

```
.....
```

What I would like is to read this file in a python dictionary, where each new person is id-ed. 
i.e. Person with ID 1 will have the names ['ann','anna','ana'] 
and will have the feature ['A 65-year old woman that has no known health issues but has a medical history of Schizophrenia.' ]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post any code that you tried?

Comment: What have you tried? Asking "any suggestions?" is too vague.

Comment: So, are you asking how to read from a text file or what structure to use for the data?

Comment: @not_a_robot : up until now I have uploaded much simpler data files so I have no idea how to start reading and organizing this document into a dictionary.

Comment: @christinabo : I believe that a dictionary is what I need, but other format suggestions are also welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your input file is `lo.txt`. It can be added to dictionary this way:

```
file = open('lo.txt')
final_data = []
feature = []
names = []
for line in file.readlines():
    if ("feature") in line:
        data =  line.replace("\n","").split(":")
        feature=data[1]
        final_data.append({
        'names': names,
        'feature': feature
        })
        names = []
        feature = []
    if ("name") in line:
        data =  line.replace("\n","").split(":")
        names.append(data[1])

print final_data
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work

```
result = {}
f = open("document.txt")
contents = f.read()
info = contents.split('==== new person ===')

for i in range(len(info)):
    info[i].split('\n')
    names = []
    features = []

    for j in range(len(info[i])):
         info[i][j].split(':')

         if info[i][j][0] == 'name':
             names.append(info[i][j][1])

         else:
             features.append(info[i][j][1])

    result[i] = {'names': names,'features': features}
    print(result)
```

This should give you something like:

```
{0: {'names': ['ana', 'anna', 'ann'], features:['...', '...']}}
```

e.t.c

Comment: Thanks, I am trying this out as it appears to be quite close to what I want to achieve. There is a problem with my .txt file though as the split function leaves ' ' at the place of the split character

Comment: Ok so it worked perfectly with some small modifications. Add filter(None,info) to clean up white spaces. Also rather than info[i].split(':') I had to reassign info[i]=info[i].split(':') and filter this too. Same for info[i][j].

Comment: Ok. Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that may work for you:

```
f = open("documents.txt").readlines()

f = [i.strip('\n') for i in f]


final_condition = f[len(f)-1]

f.remove(final_condition)

names = [i.split(":")[1] for i in f]


the_dict = {}



the_dict["names"] = names
the_dict["features"] = final_condition

print the_dict
```

All it does is split the names at ":" and take the last element of the resulting list (the names) and keep it for the list names.